# Как настроить freeradius для авторизации беспроводных устройств в Cisco WLC (по MAC filtering)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cisco, freeradius

По вот этой инструкции https://mangospot.net/install-freeradius-pgsql-on-debian-or-ubuntu.html если использовать подключение через SQL (postgresql) все работает.

Но возникает вопрос, как сделать свою таблицу с нужными полями (мак адрес, пользователь, группа и т.д.) в которой пользователь будет относится к (страна, регион, офис и т.д.) а группа будет иметь (страна, город, офис, доступ - в последующем access list) в которых пользователь имеет права подключится к Wi-Fi сети этим девайсом. В дальнейшем также хотелось бы чтобы был функционал для динамической передачи влана (dynamic private group id) для добавления удобного функционала.

Точнее даже создание таблицы тут не рассматривается. Рассматривается как freeradius конфигурить или где конфигурить чтобы он подружился с подобной таблицей

Уверен и знаю есть специальные инструменты (профессиональное ПО и железо) которое способно на подобные хотелки. Которые можно настроить без геморроя (отчасти).

В любом случае думаю тема будет интересна всем кто интересуется альтернативными и бесплатными инструментами